# Create GRUB Entry for Booting into CentOS Installation Media

Tags: centos, installation, grub2

Normally when installing CentOS 7, you download the ISO, write it to a thumb drive and boot it. However, I have a unique scenario where I'd like to be able to place the CentOS 7 installation files on a system's `/boot/` partition and create a custom `GRUB2` entry that can boot into that environment. This can then be used to install CentOS 7 on the same system.

I know this sounds silly, but I have my reasons..

After doing some research, I'm trying to piece together how this works. Here is what I'm seeing in my head currently:

1. `GRUB2` would load the CentOS 7 kernel `vmlinuz` and `initrd.img`.
2. After initializing the kernel and loading the `initrd.img` into memory, the `dracut-initqueue` service starts.
3. The `dracut-initqueue` processes will then try to load the `stage2` image, which holds the installation runtime (Anaconda in this case).
4. Finally, the CentOS installation process kicks off.

So to start I..

1. Downloaded the ISO, mounted it and copied the `/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz`, `/images/pxeboot/initrd.img` and `/LiveOS/squashfs.img` (which I believe contains the `stage2` image) files to my `/boot/` partition.
2. Added the below entry to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.

```
menuentry "CentOS 7 Installation" {
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
linux   /centos7-install/vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img stage2=/centos7-install/squashfs.img
initrd  /centos7-install/initrd.img
}
```

After doing the above, I would hope that I would at least get up to loading Anaconda, however instead it simply loads up to "dracut-initqueue timeout" messages. Sadly, I haven't had any luck finding any logs that hint towards exactly what went wrong.

Would anyone happen to have any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line

```
linux   /centos7-install/vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img stage2=/centos7-install/squashfs.img
```

with

```
linux   /centos7-install/vmlinuz inst.repo=<source>
```

where `<source>` can be `http://host/path` with a complete copy of the directories and files on the full installation DVD. Optionally, you can extract files from "boot" ISO and copy just `.treeinfo` file from "DVD" ISO.
See additional options (like NFS) in the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/chap-anaconda-boot-options#list-boot-options-sources).

Of course, network access is required to use this method "as is".